How to change Android studio JDK
How to make Android studio use Java 17?
I get error
Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11. Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
I add to the system PATH 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17`
My IDE shows that is using the SDK 17.
the org.gradle.java.home is set to C:\\Program Files\\Android\\Android Studio\\jre
what is going wrong?

What happens if you use the built in JDK? Setting > Build Tools > Gradle > Change to jbr-17

Goto File -> Settings -> Build -> Execution -> Deployment -> Build -> Tools -> Gradle.
Note : make sure you are already installed java 17

